# Android MVVM design - should i split my viewmodel class in two?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have an app with 2 distinctly seperate modes, (setup and run timers).

The app allows multi factor inputs from a user on one fragment and once the user wants the timer started, the app switches to a running fragment to show information about their running timer and it's setup.
I've designed an MVVM architecture for this, with my own class that extends `ViewModel`, my shared viewmodel has two distinctly different types of logic, setup logic (to check, parse and revise inappropriate user inputs), and running timer logic (to manage all the logic, data and state for a running timer from a user's inputs).

My shared viewmodel class is not small as the process of checking all permutations of user input is complex.  I'm wondering is it a bad idea to put all this logic into one viewmodel class? The setup portion is designed to be simple and all setup state is saved (so 10-20 seconds for the user to setup a timer seems appropriate), whereas the timer is designed to be allowed to run for hours, largely with the screen off.
 
Should I split the viewmodel logic into two different viewmodel classes to make a running timer more memory efficient?

I see a clear seperation of concerns and once I have my Room database designed and programmed, only the running timer will save data to the database. I want to keep the fragment classes as lightweight as possible.  If this is a sensible design choice, ill need to be careful with memory leaks between the two states, otherwise im defeating the purpose.

Edited to differentiate between the ViewModel object and a Shared viewmodel idea

Comment: at the end of the day this is all up to you. feel like your class is doing too much ? violating solid princples ? then split it. don't really know or don't care ? then don't. not really much we can give you here as a _factual_ answer as this isn't software design and you're not actually facing a problem from running your application

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, i feel im violating the principle of "only use the minimum memory you need for any app state" - so ive decided to split the shared viewmodel up.

Comment: no problem, please don't consider my comment rude as that wasn't the intention, but in these situations it's honestly up to you and how you want to design your software, there isn't really a right or a wrong way _factually_

Comment: Oh it wasnt rude, you were spot on!  Im very new to android, so im also aware of how little i really know and sometimes an "unknown unknown" can seriously bite you in the butt later on.

Comment: questions like these i always find a bit amusing, as people love to throw around mvvm and other architectures, trying to follow the latest and greatest patterns, but you should always value 1) general logic and 2) solid principles over architectures. single responsibility _should_ stay true regardless of which architecture you're following, although people can also take this _too_ far. a reason why i don't really bother with these types of questions anymore, as software debate is a draining topic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [a_local_nobody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4729721/a-local-nobody) says, it's up to you to decide how to design your app and distribute the responsibilities.

In case you are looking for our opinion about your philosophical doubts, I have to say that although the concept of the [Shared ViewModels](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) is very widespread, I am not a big fan.

In my projects, the most common and logical thing is that **each ViewModel manages the logic of a single view**. I always treat Shared ViewModels as an exception to the rule, since **abusing them usually leads to a very tightly coupled code, very difficult to test and with unexpected side effects**.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  I'll split the viewmodel into two, one per fragment.  In principle when these are scoped to their respective fragments it will keep memory usage much lower.

Your comments on making one viewmodel per UI component seem to be spot on - as per the Lyla Fujiwara blog post on viewmodels. [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e).  quote "In general, you’ll make a ViewModel class for each screen in your app"